# Where is the standard output of QtCreator when debugging?

Tags: qt-creator, windbg

I just realized the following when debugging a CMake (non-qt) project with QtCreator (not using it because of Qt but because it's a nice IDE) and CDB.

The program has a simple `cout` code line which is properly displayed in the "Application Output" pane when I run the program with `Ctrl+R`. However, if I debug the same build&run configuration with `F5`, I cannot see any output.
Where does QtCreator forward stdout to in the second case?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you figure out a solution at the time?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Since it was debug output of a GUI application, I've logged it to %TEMP% instead

Comment: @quimnuss If you find a fix or even just an explanation for this behavior however, post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: There aren't that many entries referring to it, just this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17389157/no-application-output-in-qtcreator-debug

Comment: Kind of found a solution, see answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the output printed on the debugging logs, which is a pane under Window->Views->Debugger Log

The right pane shows the expected output. Not a full solution but a very close workaround.

I believe qt creator sees only the output from cdb and it doesn't forward the program's output, but only its own. In fact, the application output pane displays one line of cdb's output related to a system call I make within my program.

This workaround causes a weird side-effect. When cdb hits a breakpoint, the colorscheme of that pane gets reset to default.

On a sidenote, there was a [closed bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-3902) report stating

> There is a difference to the old debugging engine in that the
>   printf()-output of console-applications is suppressed in
>   debug/console-builds of Qt Creator builds. In previous versions, the
>   output used to go to the terminal Qt Creator was started in.

Not true in my case, as launching qtcreator from cmd detaches from cmd.

Comment: In Windows, I'm doing "fprintf(stderr,...)" and I'm not seeing it appear in the Debugger log. Lots of other incomprehensible stuff though.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `std::endl` or `std::flush` (if you don't want to change line) at the end of `cout`, e.g. `std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;`

Comment: Actually, in my case that was the main reason. Seems that qt window is hooked to streams' flush calls and updates the window content only when stdout / stderr is flushed. This resolved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, `OutputDebugString()` goes to the "Application Output" window.

You can filter out noise by adding your own Message function:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qInstallMessageHandler